# jsTree load and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have two questions regarding jsTree:

1. I am generating a jsTree using JSON with struts2. At the first time tree displayed correctly. But on the button click I want to reload that tree with different data into the same div. On the button click I am giving the same action name which is given to the first time to generate jstree.
2. If I am clicking on any node of the tree then I want an id of that node and if that node has any parent then also want a parent node id of that node again parent node has parent then id of that parent node also

Example

```
    Parent 1
       |__Parent 2
            |__Child 1
```

I am clicking on Child 1 then I want id of Child 1, Parent 2, Parent 1 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the full path to your node you can use get_path

```
// The true means it will return the ID's of the parent, therefore ALL NODES need an ID
var parents = $("#your_jstree").jstree("get_path",$("#the_node"),true); 
$.each(parents, function(k, v){
    // Log down the ID's
    console.log(v);
});
```

Full example

```
var ids = $(this).closest(".jstree").jstree("get_path", $(this), true);
var path = "";
$.each(ids, function (k, v) {
    if (k == 0) return;

    if (path != "")
        path += "/";

    path += clone.html();
});
```

Will return /parent 1/parent 2/Child 1

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you really browsed the documentation, but here is some stuff that could help you :

for your first question, you can use rollback : http://luban.danse.us/jazzclub/javascripts/jquery/jsTree/reference/_examples/5_others.html
Refresh can be an option too : http://luban.danse.us/jazzclub/javascripts/jquery/jsTree/reference/_examples/2_operations.html

For your second question, you can use the callbacks : http://luban.danse.us/jazzclub/javascripts/jquery/jsTree/reference/_examples/3_callbacks.html

`._get_parent` will help you too :

> ._get_parent ( node )
>
> Gets the LI element representing the parent of the passed node.
>   Returns false on failure. mixed node
>
> This can be a DOM node, jQuery node or selector pointing to an element
>   within the tree, whose parent we want.

See full documentation for more details : http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core